# Tab suppression callback

Tags: facebook, callback, tabs, notifications, suppression

I have a tab app and I'd like to know if there is a way to get a notification or to setup a callback for when a user suppress the tab from his Facebook page? Because I noticed that even if you remove the tab, you don't necessarily  deauthorize the application (and for me it's not the same operation at all).

Thank you for helping me.